# When should I remove an user's login cookie?

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies

I have a table like this:

```
// cookies
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| id | user_id |       token       |   expire   |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| 1  | 32423   | dki3j4rf9u3e40... | 1467586386 |
| 2  | 65734   | erhj5473fv34gv... | 1467586521 |
| 3  | 32423   | 9b0u2ejfd43k4r... | 1467586619 |
| 4  | 21432   | 8u34ijf34t43gf... | 1467586640 |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
```

Table above stores all login cookies. Each user may have multiple rows into table above *(each row is for one device)*.

Ok, there is three cases that I have to remove a row from that table:

1. User signs out (single row)
2. Old rows (single row)
3. User changes his password (all rows)

Well I have an idea and I need some advises about that: When login cookie exists and no row matched in the database, I remove that cookie from client browser. Is that ok? Or I shouldn't do that?

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE['login']) ) {

    // db connection here
    $stm = $db->prepare('SELECT id, name, lname, reputation, email, notification 
                         FROM users WHERE cookie = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stm->execute(array($_COOKIE['login']));
    $num_rows = $stm->fetch();

    if ( $num_rows ) {
        // all fine
    } else {
        unset($_COOKIE['login']);
        setcookie('login', '', time() - 3600, '/');
    }

}
```

Please focus on these lines:

```
unset($_COOKIE['login']);
setcookie('login', '', time() - 3600, '/');
```

Well, what I'm doing is correct?

Comment: you only have one `key` for the cookie array, therefore the user can only ever have ONE value stored in that key. therefore only the most recent stored value should be kept around, because all the previous ones probably got overwritten.

Comment: @MarcB I'm saying when a cookie exists but its value isn't matched with the database, then that cookie is useless. Also seems kinda suspect .. I why do I need to keep it around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user sends a cookie, which is not in your database, you cannot do anything with it. You do not know if it is a valid cookie or a forged one. You do not know to which user it belongs.

You can safely delete it. It would be overwritten with a new proper login anyway.